# LG G4 H815 kernel do not detect slimport

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Lg g4 h815 stock rom use anx7816 kernel module to detect slimport.
I've recompiled the kernel and checked anx7816 is selected at kernel configuration but my custom kernel do not detect the slimport.

I see in the original kernel in dmesg that anx7816 find the display port and it show this message when hdmi is attached:

```
[24657.373888 / 11-22 18:45:04.818][2] [anx7816] sp_tx_pclk_calc : PCLK = 148.4
[24657.374358 / 11-22 18:45:04.818][2] [anx7816] sp_tx_bw_lc_sel : pixel_clk = 148.4
[24657.393605 / 11-22 18:45:04.838][2] [anx7816] hdmi_rx_new_vsi_int : *HDMI_RX Interrupt: NEW VSI packet.
[24657.395268 / 11-22 18:45:04.838][2] [anx7816] hdmi_rx_new_vsi_int : Setup VSI package!
[24657.416099 / 11-22 18:45:04.858][2] [anx7816] sp_tx_enable_video_input : Slimport Video is enabled!
```

but my custom kernel compiled with anx7816 say nothing like that.

What could cause my kernel to do not detect slimport ? Does it need a additional .so file from the orriginal rom?

EDIT:

I did like lg said , got krnel from http://opensource.lge.com/osSch/list?types=ALL&search=h815 , and i tried to recompile it :

```
make ARCH=arm64 p1_global_com-perf_defconfig
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=../prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android- -j4
```

My new rom boots all is fine , but kernel do not see the slimport like original kernel do.I do not understand why kernel do not see the slimport .All others works

Comment: you're asking people to guess what code you have created. You need to include a minimal test case (of code) that shows what you have tried. Good luck.

Comment: I just followed the lge instruction about how to recompile the kernel.I got the kernel from http://opensource.lge.com/osSch/list?types=ALL&search=h815 and I did what they said